# PDF resizing in html (also scrolling needed)

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, resize

I need to show pdf file with scrolling and resizing.
Ive read that div should be used. I tried to do it by analogy with img-wrapper, but somehow it didnt work. I see no pdf. Any suggestions?
Heres my code:

html:

```
<div id="myPdfDiv" class="pdf-image">
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="view_pdf.js" id="view_pdf" data-url="<?php echo $rows['img']; ?>"></script>
```

js:

```
imgUrl = "http://aspirant.beget.tech/upload/images/1.Pdf"

$("#body").append("<p><embed src=" + imgUrl + " type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%' class='pdf_image'></p>");
```

css:

```
.pdf-image {
overflow: auto;
height: 200px;
resize: both;
background-color: blue;
position: relative;
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:auto;
}

.pdf-image > img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: -50%;*/
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a few syntax mistakes remove the # from body make it `$("body")` then add a let or var or const to the imgUrl `var imgUrl = "http://aspirant.beget.tech/upload/images/1.Pdf"` * and try iframe instead of embed
this is the code I could write, 
P.S. The browser might block the content you should allow to unblock it

```js
let imgUrl = "http://aspirant.beget.tech/upload/images/1.Pdf";

$("body").append(`<p><iframe src='${imgUrl}'></iframe></p>`);
```

You also had some issues with commas " ' ` I fixed them also

Comment: Thank you @NairiAregHatspanyan but resizing doesnt work in your code. Also snippet said to  me $ is undefined

Comment: Another question: pdf is displayed in the left. How to make it centered or moved to the right?

Comment: Easy- give it a parent wich has a `width:100%` of the body, give it flex and justify content center  `display:flex;justify-content:center`, $ is undefined means that your code doesn't understand jQuery you should link it and it will work

Comment: Dear Nairi Areg Hatspanyan, how to be with resizing? It still doesnt work